# Is there any way to output SOAP Envelope when using Python Fuel-SDK?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api, fuel-sdk, subscriber

Would anyone know if there is a way to output the SOAP Envelope that is generated when using the Pythin Fuel-SDK, e.g. the SOAP envelope when making the below call:

```
getSub = ET_Client.ET_Subscriber()
getSub.auth_stub = stubObj
getSub.props = ["SubscriberKey", "EmailAddress", "Status"]
getSub.search_filter = {'Property' : 'SubscriberKey','SimpleOperator' : 'equals','Value' : SubscriberTestEmail};
getResponse = getSub.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have it in the [Marketing Cloud Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieve_a_subscriber_via_the_web_service_api.htm)

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Header>
    <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <UsernameToken>
            <Username>USERNAME_GOES_HERE</Username>
            <Password>PASSWORD_GOES_HERE</Password>
        </UsernameToken>
    </Security>
</Header>
<Body>
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <RetrieveRequest>
            <ObjectType>Subscriber</ObjectType>
            <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
            <Properties>EmailAddress</Properties>
            <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
            <Properties>Status</Properties>
            <Properties>UnsubscribedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>ID</Properties>
            <Properties>Client.PartnerClientKey</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                <Property>SubscriberKey</Property>
                <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                <Value>SubscriberTestEmail</Value>
            </Filter>
        </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
</Body>
```

Give it a try with Postman.